# Ghostscript -sPageList produces stackunderflow error and quits

Tags: ghostscript

I want to print certain pages in a different order with -sPageList input.pdf file with ghostscript

```
> "gswin64c.exe" -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dMaxBitmap=300 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sFONTPATH="C:\Windows\Fonts" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPageList=2,4,9-11,12-13,5-8 -o out.pdf in.pdf
```

I produces the error:

> **** Error : rangecheck processing PageList
>   **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting. Unrecoverable error: stackunderflow in .quit Operand stack:
>       1

Though calling the same with the following code it works out fine.

```
"gswin64c.exe" -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dMaxBitmap=300 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sFONTPATH="C:\Windows\Fonts" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 in.pdf -dFirstPage=4 -dLastPage=4 in.pdf -dFirstPage=9 -dLastPage=11 in.pdf -dFirstPage=12 -dLastPage=13 in.pdf -dFirstPage=5 -dLastPage=8 in.pdf -o out.pdf in.pdf
```

Can anybody tell the reason why

> -sPageList=2,4,9-11,12-13,5-8

**or**

> -sPageList="2,4,9-11,12-13,5-8"

does not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use PageList to alter the order, the page numbers have to increase.

This is because the same syntax is used for PostScript and PCL input, and those formats are not random-access, they are streamed, so having gone past page 5 we can't rewind the stream and go back to it.

In the second case you are running the input file multiple times, each time reading a subset of pages. You **can** do that with PostScript and other input languages as well, of course, but naturally it is slower.